# Load file to application local storage

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

Is there an ability to load files like documents, articles from server and store them in application local storage using Filemanager? And how then users can read these files? Do they have access to that folder?

Comment: of course u can download any kind of file and save it in documents directory for any use

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps for downloading and saving file in `NSDocumentDirectory`

```
// Determine local file path
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0],@"fileName.doc"];   //it could be any file type

// Download and write to file
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.filePathFromServerLocation.com"];

//and write to file
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

This way your file will be save at `filePath` and u can use it in future whatever the way u like.

Opening a file in iOS:

1. Using a `webview`

   ```
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"document" ofType:@"pdf"];
   NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
   [webView loadRequest:request];
   ```
2. using a `UIDocumentInteractionController`.
3. Have a look at this Apple sample code for [ZoomingPDFViewer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010281)

Comment: If I will add an ability in my app that user can load books from server how he can open this book without my application? For example open a book within some reader app.

Comment: If its a `pdf` file then iOS can open it automatically in-app or in iBooks app.. I will need more info about your server file.

Comment: On server there will be only photos, doc, docx files and pdf.

Comment: you can use `UIDocumentInteractionController` to open files natively.

Comment: So there is no ability to access to these files without my app? Like filemanager in Android.

Comment: Nope. all these files will be save with your app documents directory, which will be removed if u delete the app. You can, however, export the file from the app into another third party file manager app like `Dropbox`, `Evernote` or `FileMaster` .

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try to open my files in application.